# When does Daredevil: End of Days take place?

Tags: marvel, daredevil

*Daredevil: End of Days* deals with Ben Urich trying to piece together Matt Murdock's life before he was killed by Bullseye.

A number of his old friends, teammates, allies, and foes show up. Everyone has visibly aged. But no date is given and no real indication of timeframe is ever really mentioned.

How far in the future is *End of Days* estimated to take place?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that there seems to be no canon explanation of the year in which End of Days is set. Right from the word 'go' it's worth mentioning that the ages of the various characters within the Marvel Universe often make little or no chronological sense, with heroes and villains becoming older and younger purely to make crossovers and match-ups more accessible for readers.

The [blurb](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/24777/daredevil_end_of_days_2012_1) for title #1 mentions that it's set "**In the near future**" but that's as far as they go. The newspapers in the serial are undated and there's no in-universe mention of how long it's been since Daredevil died which makes dating it almost impossible, even if we knew the year of his death.

Basically all we're left with are contextual clues. Ben Urich is usually drawn his late 30s or early 40s whereas in DD: End of Days he looks more like his late 50s. The same goes for the other characters he meets so we can assume that it's set around 2030-ish.

[image]

Or maybe not.

Comment: Twenty minutes into the future.